# Getting to parent property in subclasses that uses a baseclass

Tags: python

I am creating a module where I need to define a bunch of objects that will be used in the same module.

My ultimate goal is for something like this to work;

```
m = Mod()
obj1 = m.T1('text')
obj2 = m.T2(23)
m.togheter(obj1, obj2)
```

The problem I have is that I need to keep track of an ID in my subclasses.
I've gotten this far, which gives me an `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute '_cid'` from `return super(Mod.ModObj, self)._cid`

```
class Mod(object):
    current_cid = 0

    @property
    def _cid(self):
        c = self.current_cid
        self.current_cid += 1
        return c

    def togheter(self, obj1, obj2):
        # Do something with obj1.text and obj2.number here...
        return True

    class ModObj(object):
        @property
        def _cid(self):
            return super(Mod.ModObj, self)._cid

    class T1(ModObj):
        def __init__(self, text):
            self.text = text
            print self._cid

    class T2(ModObj):
        def __init__(self, number):
            self.number = number
            print self._cid

m = Mod()
m.T1('text')
m.T2(23)
print m.current_cid  # Should return 2
```

What is wrong here? I tried several other "trial and error" ways as well, but I am starting to think that I am doing this the completely wrong way...

Comment: `Nesting != Inheritance`. Why are theses classes nested at all?

Answer (score 0):

`ModObj` doesn't inherit from `Mod`; it's just a nested class that inherits from `object`, and `object` indeed does not have a property (or any attribute) named `_cid`.

Comment: Thanks.. I though I could access the parent instance like this.. Any hints on how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your class `ModObj` is *not* a subclass of Mod, but a member. You probably want to say `class ModObj(Mod)`.

Also note that as long as you do not override `_cid` in your subclass, there is no need to use `super` at all, as the superclass members automatically exist in the subclass (that's the point of class inheritance).

Finally - is that really what you want? It seems to me that you want each `Mod` instance to have a unique ID, and for each `ModObj` instance to inherit the ID of a specific `Mod` instance. Class inheritance will *not* do that. You might be looking for a parent-child relation.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications.. Yes, I want each Mod instance to have their its own cid counter and ModObj (T1 and T2) to be able to set and read the counter using the _cid property.